# Where can I find the segment id of a tag in Mailchimp?

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to use the Mailchimp API v3 to add tags to multiple subscribers. [According to the Mailchimp API documentation](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/segments/#create-post_lists_list_id_segments_segment_id), I need the segment id of the tag to do this. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 11):

Found it.

1) Log into the [Mailchimp API Playground](https://us1.api.mailchimp.com/playground/?_ga=2.27689596.1788242986.1551482180-1350812874.1511389229)
2) Click **Lists**, then **Subresources**, then **segments**.
3) Click on the relevant segment.
4) You'll see: "id: {your_segment_id}" under **Details**.

Comment: I can't see my segment is this list. But I can the segment name with created date under Audience-> Manage contacts-> Segments but segment id is not listed there. How can I show my segment into Mailchimp API Playground? or find segment id under audience?

Comment: I am looking for a 'static segment' / 'tag' ID, but can't see it ANYWHERE..?!

Comment: If you have more than 10 segments you won't find it listed in the API playground because the default paging group is 10 and it only displays the first page. You can use Postman to get a full list.

Answer (score 8):

I think I could find more simple way to find `segment_id`.

1. Log into [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) using your account
2. Go to audience->View Contacts. Click on Manage Contacts and select Segments
3. Right click on your segment and do copy link
4. Paste copied link anywhere to get `segment_id` from URL. URL would be like
   https://us20.admin.mailchimp.com/lists/segments/view-members?id=xxxx&segment_id=xxxx